# How to add triangle crevices to the bottom of my bulb model like the 2D image?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

I am trying to get the above model to look something like the vector image below, but in 3D, I am not able to picture how I can get the below look without making the mesh get weird shading.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think i would use image as plane of the shape, then extrude vertices (just for one side) and then use the screw modifier. If that result is ok, apply screw modifier and delete the triangle faces at top and bottom and make one ngon face and inset that a few times. Then subdiv modifier.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: It's hard to guess how you imagine that in 3D, maybe tell a bit more

Comment: @moonboots so in front view, I want the model to be able to show the triangle crevices going up as in the vector image for both front and back, same for the bottom sections of the bulb, somehow I am not able to correctly model that for the curved surface

Answer (score 1):

Your model is almost fine. Just that the face orientation is inverted which caused your shading issues. To resolve that, select the red object and <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* then press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices and go to menu *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside* or shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to fix the normals so it appears blue.

[image]

Then you could try to get rid of some edge loops or try to space the edge loops a bit to give the subdivision more room to smoothen things out by selecting an edge loop with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> and pressing <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to move the edge loops around. Then maybe add another level of subdivision.

[image]

Then you have [non-manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) in this selected faces area which causes the weird shading. Delete these faces:

[image]

And you have duplicate overlapping vertices in this object which causes weird shading. Go <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>A</kbd> > *Merge By Distance*.

[image]